# Generating a unique product ID in IBM MDM

Tags: ibm-infosphere, ibm-information-server

I wish to generate a unique product ID using IBM InfoSphere Master Data Management Collaborative Edition (MDM CE). Has anyone had such scenarios in any other implementation and if so how they have done that?

The requirements are as follows:

1. MDM CE has to generate a unique product ID for a "live product" and not for "testing products". This ID should be same for the product across environments (Dev, Testing, QA, Prod) as some of the systems still hard code the Product ID to make their functionalities work.
2. Not every environment needs to follow the workflow once its done in lower environments.
3. Testing, QA environments data then can't be cleaned up as live products are also existing and being worked upon in there.
4. We do still have enhancements to the model and functionalities going on in parallel every 2-4 weeks sprints.
    
   What are the possibilities here to use different companies in a same environment. Lets say each environment having 2 different companies i.e. One for live products creation and other for testing products/testing new functionalities. What are the challenges in doing so:

a. From a code perspective (How do we achieve this when we using devops model to have single jar file and deploy it via automated process in each env)?

b. From a data perspective

c. From access perspective (Can we enable different LDAP roles per company ?)

Answer (score 0):

a. From a code perspective (How do we achieve this when we using devops model to have single jar file and deploy it via automated process in each env)?
you can automate the deployment using  CM or  EDP Jenkins

b. From a data perspective
you can try using itemObj.getPipeDelimitedCSVRepresentation() which  will return the entire Item data as | deliminator  
and then you can parse this data and create a brand new item  in nay environment

c. From access perspective (Can we enable different LDAP roles per company ?)
Yes you can enable multiple roles on  LDAP and the name of the MDM CE roles and the role created in LDAP must be same